# simplifying $\int{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}\ dx$

Tags: calculus

i used the substitution $$x=\frac{\sin{u}}{2}$$
and I got to $$\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{2}\sin{(2\arcsin(2x))}+\arcsin(2x))+c$$
and $$2x=\sin(u)$$
and drew a triangle
[image]
now im stuck...
the answer is
[image]

Comment: Duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/a/153851/243873

Comment: use the fact that $\sin (2t) = 2 \sin t \cos t, \sin t = 2x, \cos t = \sqrt{-1-4x^2}$ to simplify $\sin(2 \sin^{-1}(2x))$

Comment: i meant to write $\cos t = \sqrt{1-4x^2}$ above.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}\sin{(2\arcsin(2x))}=\frac{1}{2}\sin{2u}=\frac{1}{2}\sin{4u\sqrt{1-4u^2}}$ ...? can you answer it because i cant get it... @abel

Comment: i posted some explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the first expression in you answer: you have 
$$\begin{align}\sin\left(2\sin^{-1}(2x)\right) &= \sin(2t)\\
& = 2\sin t \cos t \\
&=2 \times 2x\times \sqrt{1 -\sin^2 t}\\
&=4x\sqrt{1-4x^2}\end{align}$$ i have used $t = \sin^{-1}(2x), \sin t = 2x, \cos t = \sqrt{1-4x^2}.$

Answer (score 1):

You need to appeal to an identity at the end, before using the triangle:

$\int (1-4x^{2})^{1(/2)}dx=\int \cos ^{2}zdz=\int (\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos 2z)dz=\frac{1}{2}z-\frac{1}{4}\sin 2z=\frac{1}{2}(z)-\frac{1}{4}(2\sin z\cos z)=\frac{1}{2}\arcsin x+\frac{1}{2}x(1-x^{2})^{1/2}+C$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: let $u = \sqrt{1-4x^2}, v = x$, can you proceed with integration by parts ?

Comment: parts won't work here.

Comment: maybe I should have tagged trig sub sry

Comment: Parts DOES work here.

Comment: You're lettng $v=x$ but there is no factor of $x$ in the integrand. Are we talking about the same integral? You could try lettng $v'=1$, and $u$ the root but I don't think that will work because in the second integral you get $x^{2}$ in the numerator and then the root in the denominator. Then you're back to trig substitution, aren't you?

Comment: I'm getting $x(1-4x^{2})^{1/2}-4\int \frac{x^{2}}{(1-4x^{2})^{1/2}}dx$ by parts. So....

Comment: write $-4x^2 = -4x^2 + 1 - 1$, and split it into $2$ parts.

Comment: Got it. Nice! Thanks.